# Redirect page at a specific date and time referencing the server time

Tags: javascript

So i'm not the best in the world at JS, but what i'm looking to do is to have a page redirect to another page

(website/something1.html to website/something2.html)

at a specific time and date (04/03/2019/20:00) to avoid annoying timezone problems i thought it would be best to just have it check if the date and time matches the date and time where the server is hosted which happens to be the same timezone as what i'm looking for.

So i looked up some questions here on stackoverflow and found almost what i was looking for:

```
// For todays date;
Date.prototype.today = function () { 
return ((this.getDate() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getDate() +"/"+ 
(((this.getMonth()+1) < 10)?"0":"") + (this.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ 
this.getFullYear() +this.getMinutes();
}

if((new Date().today()) >= "10/09/2018/00:18")
{
location.href ="google.com";
}
else
{
location.href="current location url";
}
```

so i used this as my starting point and tried to edit it to my needs which didn't really work at all.

I hope someone here is able to help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that javascript will get the time from the client side, not server side, still, you can specify it for a specific timezone.

This code will do what you're looking for

```
if( new Date() >= new Date('09/18/2018 00:18') ) {
    location.href = "http://google.com";
} else {
    // another location
}
```

Please note that the date format is mm/dd/yyyy...

Comment: That sure does look simpler. Slight problem though. using the code causes my page not to load unless it's past the given time.

Comment: Can you show me how exactly you implemented the code? 
you shouldn't use an else statement if you don't want to redirect the user, my guessing is that you used this (location.href="current location url") which means the user will be facing an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: I am not sure the redirect.js file is called in this page, but I can see you have a <script> tag at the end of your /js/custom.wedding.js file, remove it and it should work fine.

Comment: Yeah, Sorry that was my fault. Thank you very much for the help!